# Laravel copy record and duplicate with new values But not with unique field

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to duplicate my records with a new value.

I am using these codes and they are working well with unique field (id).

```
$task = tableName::find($request->id);
    $newTask = $task->replicate();
    $newTask->newField= 2;
    $newTask->save();
```

My table looks like :

| id | no | first | second | newField |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 1000 | 650 | 1 |
| 2 | 52 | 4500 | 45 | 1 |
| 3 | 45 | 1250 | 75 | 1 |
| 4 | 58 | 7500 | 86 | 1 |
| 5 | 45 | 250 | 72 | 1 |

i want to duplicate all my rows with a new value. **Just newField must be 2.**

Comment: $task = tableName::where('no',$request->no)->first(); with this row i can duplicate first record.

Comment: whats the issue you are facing ? your this code works fine for 1st record ?

Comment: i want to replicate all no:45 rows with a newField value (2)

Comment: i know i have to use a loop. But i could not find how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch all records against a specific `no`. Try something like this

```
$tasks = tableName::where('no',$request->id)->where('newField',1)->get();
foreach($tasks as $task)
{
    $newTask = $task->replicate();
    $newTask->newField= 2;
    $newTask->save();
}
```

Please check official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#select-statements) as well.

Comment: works perfect! thx